# iPhone 12 compression of video making videos blue colored

Tags: ios, swift, video, compression, iphone12

I'm trying to compress videos selected from the photo library of the iPhone device and uploading them to the server. Its working for all devices except iPhone 12. On iPhone 12 videos are showing all blue and same to server. Following is the code I'm using to compress videos.

```
func convertVideo(phAsset : PHAsset, handler:@escaping (_ compressedData: Data?)-> Void){

        var compressedData: Data? = nil
       PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: phAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
           if let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
               do {
                   let videoData = try  Data.init(contentsOf: asset.url)
                   print(asset.url)
                   //self.orginalVideo = asset.url
                   print("File size before compression: \(Double(videoData.count / 1048576)) mb")
               let compressedURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + NSUUID().uuidString + ".MP4")
                   print(compressedURL)
                   self.compressVideo(inputURL: asset.url , outputURL: compressedURL) { (exportSession) in
                       guard let session = exportSession else {
                           return
                       }
                       switch session.status {
                       case .unknown:
                           print("unknown")
                        handler(compressedData)
                           break
                       case .waiting:
                           print("waiting")
                        handler(compressedData)
                           break
                       case .exporting:
                           print("exporting")
                        handler(compressedData)
                           break
                       case .completed:
                           do {
                           compressedData = try  Data.init(contentsOf: compressedURL)
                               //self.compressVideo = compressedURL
                            print("File size AFTER compression: \(Double(compressedData!.count / 1048576)) mb")
                            handler(compressedData)
                           }
                           catch{
                              print(error)
                            handler(compressedData)
                           }


                       case .failed:
                           print("failed")
                        handler(compressedData)
                           break
                       case .cancelled:
                           print("cancelled")
                        handler(compressedData)
                           break
                       @unknown default:
                        break
                       }
                   }
               } catch {
                   print(error)
                handler(compressedData)
                   //return
               }
           }
       })


   }

   func compressVideo(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?)-> Void) {
       let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)
       guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else {
           handler(nil)

           return
       }
       exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
       exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
       exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
       exportSession.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
           handler(exportSession)
       }
   }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by using LightCompressor_ios lib
https://github.com/AbedElazizShe/LightCompressor_iOS